# Logrotate Creating Empty Rotated Files

Tags: cron, logrotate

I have the following parameters set up for the log rotation of a log. `size=10M`, `rotate 800`, `copytruncate`, `missingok`. 800 rotated files are being created, but many of them are below 10M and some of them are empty with 0 size.

I have a cron setup as `* * * * *` which runs every minute to do this logrotation. I don't want this, can't understand why it is happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even i had same issues, after adding "nocreate" option issues is solved.

```
/opt/postgres/9.1/data/pg_log/postgresql*.log {
        missingok
        compress
        daily
        rotate 7
        maxage 7
        minsize 5
        notifempty
        size 5M
    nocreate
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this option:

```
notifempty
    Do not rotate the log if it is empty (this overrides the ifempty option).
```

Source: http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate

Comment: I tried that too. But still the sizes of the rotated logs are different from one another, instead of all having 10M size, Infact, some are more than 10M.

Comment: @NixMan: They won't have exactly the same size. Just look at the manual: "Log files are rotated when they grow bigger than size bytes. [...]"